# Update Table when adding Content to the SQLite Backend

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, express, electron

i have built a Table in my React Frontend which displays Data from a SQLite Table in my Expressjs Backend.

Also i built a form to insert Data in this table from the Frontend.

My problem is now, everytime i insert data i have to refresh the page to see the new insert in the Table. Is there any solution to update the table automatically when new data is written to the backend, or when i hit the "Anlegen" Button?

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      parts: [],
      isLoading: false,
      isError: false
    }
  }


async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/bestand')
    if (response.ok) {
      const parts = await response.json()
      this.setState({ parts, isLoading: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ isError: true, isLoading: false })
    }
  }

render() {
    const { parts, isLoading, isError } = this.state

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    if (isError) {
      return <div>Error</div>
    }

    return parts.length > 0
      ? (
        <table className="table" id="tblData"  >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {this.renderTableHeader()}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTableRows()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      ) : (
        <div>
          No parts.
      </div>
      )
  }

renderTableHeader = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.state.parts[0]).map(attr => 
    <th key={attr} >
    {attr}
    </th>)
  }

renderTableRows = () => {
    return this.state.parts.map(part => {
      return (
        <tr key={part.id}>
          <td>{part.Teilenummer}</td>
          <td>{part.Hersteller}</td>
          <td>{part.Beschreibung}</td>
          <td>{part.Preis}</td>
          <td>{part.SKU}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
}
export default Table
```

EDIT:
AddNew.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import Sidebar from '../Components/Sidebar'
import Table from '../Components/Table'

import '../css/Global.css'
import '../css/AddNew.css'


class New extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            Teilenummer: "",
            SKU: "",
            Hersteller: "",
            Preis: "",
            Beschreibung: "",
            answerOk: "Success",
            answerDenied: "Denied",
        };
    }


      

    render() {
        return (
<div>
<Sidebar />
<div className="container">

    <div className="box-wrapper"> 
        <div id="box2"> 

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">

                <div className="Teilenummer">
                    <label>
                    Teilenummer: 
                    <br/>
                    <input 
                        type="JSON" 
                        className="teilenrinput" 
                        name="Teilenummer" 
                        id="Teilenummer" 
                        value={this.state.Teilenummer}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        required
                    />
                    <br /><br />
                    </label>
                </div> 

                <div className="SKU">
                    <label>SKU: 
                    <br />
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="SKU" 
                        className="skuinput" 
                        id="SKU" 
                        value={this.state.SKU}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        required
                    />
                    <br /><br />
                    </label>
                </div> 

                <div className="Price">
                    <label>
                    Preis: 
                    <br />
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="Price" 
                        className="priceinput" 
                        id="Preis" 
                        value={this.state.Preis}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        required
                    />
                    <br /><br />
                    </label>
                </div> 

                <div className="Hersteller">
                  <label>
                  Hersteller: 
                  <br />
                      <input 
                        list="manufacturers"
                        name="Hersteller" 
                        id="Hersteller" 
                        className="herstellerinput"
                        value={this.state.Hersteller}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        required
                      >
                      </input>
                      <datalist id="manufacturers">
                          <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                          <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                          <option value="BMW" selected="selected">BMW</option>
                          <option value="Mercedes" selected="selected">Mercedes</option>
                          <option value="Opel" selected="selected">Opel</option>  
                      </datalist>
                  </label>
              </div>

              <div className="Beschreibung">
                  <label>
                  Beschreibung: 
                  <br />
                  <input 
                     type="text" 
                     name="Beschreibung" 
                     className="beschreibunginput" 
                     id="Beschreibung"
                     value={this.state.Beschreibung}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    required 
                  />
                  <br /><br />      
                  </label>
              </div>

              <input  class="Eintragen-Button" type="submit" value="Anlegen "/>

                       <span id="response"></span>
                       <button className="exportieren" onClick="exportTableToExcel('tblData')">Exportieren</button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <div id="box3"> 
            <div id="box4"> 
               <table className="table" id="tblData">
                <thead className="tblhead" >
                  
                   <Table />
                 
                </thead>
                 
               </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
        )
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.id;
        if (field === "Teilenummer") {
            this.setState({ Teilenummer: event.target.value });
        } else if (field === "SKU") {
            this.setState({ SKU: event.target.value });
        } else if (field === "Hersteller") {
            this.setState({ Hersteller: event.target.value });
        } else if (field === "Preis") {
            this.setState({ Preis: event.target.value });
        } else if (field === "Beschreibung") {
            this.setState({ Beschreibung: event.target.value });
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ status: "Submit" });

        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/api/teile/",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: { 
                   Teilenummer: this.state.Teilenummer, 
                   SKU: this.state.SKU,
                   Hersteller: this.state.Hersteller,
                   Preis: this.state.Preis,
                   Beschreibung: this.state.Beschreibung 
                  }
            
        }).then((response, props) => {
            
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.answer === this.state.answerOk) {
                
                this.setState({ Teilenummer: "", 
                                SKU: "", 
                                Hersteller: "",
                                Preis: "",
                                Beschreibung: "",
                                status: "Logged in" })
                alert("Success");

                
           
            } else if (response.data.answer === this.state.answerDenied) {
                this.setState({ Teilenummer: "", 
                                SKU: "", 
                                Hersteller: "",
                                Preis: "",
                                Beschreibung: "",
                                status: "Failed" })
                alert("Wrong Username or Password");
            }
        });
    
    }
}

export default New
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to update the client due to an insert operation in the backend database. You would have to "poll" the server for any changes.

Here is a custom 'useInterval' hook you could try.
[useInterval custom hook](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

I do not see an "Anlegen" button in your code but yes, you could add an onClick event/handler to it to trigger the same fetch request that's in your componentDidMount() method.

You could also use sockets and broadcast to clients following the write operation.

Comment: sorry, added the missing "AddNew" File with the Button.